# How do you show that a continuous function like $e^{-x/\text{constant}}$ is never negative?

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity

This is part of a larger question to verify that a function is a probablity distribution.

I have already shown that the sum of all values from $0$ to $\infty$ is equal to $1$ (by taking the integral from $0$ to $\infty$).

I know the next step is to show that no probability is less than $0$ which is synonymous to showing that $f(x)$ is non-negative. Is there a formal way of doing this? I would imagine I could factor if $f(x)$ was a polynomial, but I'm dealing with $e^{-x/\text{constant}}$.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=e^{-x/k}$ is positive for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Proof by contradiction

Suppose there exist a finite number of  $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and let $\bar x$ be the maximum of these  such that $e^{-\bar x/k}<0$

As we know that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{s \to 0} e^{-x/k}=0$, for Rolle's theorem there exists $c\in(\bar x,+\infty)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ that is $\dfrac{k \,e^{-\frac{k}{c}}}{c^2}=0$ which means that $e^{-\frac{k}{c}}=0$ and $c>\bar x$ which is contradiction because we said that $\bar x$ was the largest.

Answer (score 6):

$e$ to anything is always positive, no matter the power.

Comment: "… no matter the *real* power".

Comment: @PatrickStevens: in the frame of probability distributions, complex arguments are rarely irrelevant.

Comment: This assumes of course that "anything" is a real number. When imaginary numbers get involved, then you have $e^{i\pi} = -1,$ etc.